# Problems with clear case plugin eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, clearcase, eclipse-3.5

I have a following problems with eclipse, when I installed ClearCase plugin from this url http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/  :

[image]

Has anyone experienced the similar problem? I'm using Windows 7 and eclipse galileo. I've installed the plugin from this URL, what can I do to work this problem out?

**For those who can't see tinypic images**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Connect to the Rational ClearCase failed                             |
|                                                                      |
|     Connect to the Rational ClearCase failed                         |
|                                                                      |
|     Reason:                                                          |
|     Select Details >> for more information.                          |
|                                                                      |
|                                     +------------+   +------------+  |
|                                     |     OK     |   | << Details |  |
|                                     +------------+   +------------+  |
|                                                                      |
|Could not connect to the Rational Clearcase. Please ensure that proper|
|version of ClearCase is installed with the proper patches. Consult the|
|ClearCase SCM Adapter documentation for further details.              |
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|Provider name: IBM                                                    |
|Plugin name: Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter                           |
|Plugin ID: com.rational.clearcase                                     |
|Version: 7.5.0.v200910221234                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Google doesn't help much ..

Comment: i guess the problem is that may be u have to install the clear case first... after that install the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem with that plugin (except the MVFS layer does not work for now, since dynamic views are not yet supported on windows7), provided you do have the exact tree

```
yourEclipse
  eclipse
    plugins
      com.rational.clearcase.help_7.5.0.v200910221234
      com.rational.clearcase.activities_7.5.0.v200910221234
      com.rational.clearcase_7.5.0.v200910221234
    features
      com.rational.clearcase_7.5.0.v200910221234
      com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrefresh_7.5.0.v200910221234
      com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccimport.feature_7.1.0.v200905202348--08422A2_242663
```

So you can start and check if you do see this configuration.
Note: I only install it on Eclipse Galileo 3.5 and Eclipse Helios 3.6Mx.

[image: Eclipse Installation Details]

Comment: @VonC , how do I get to that info which you provided? I think I'm also using 3.5.0

Comment: @VonC, here is the image exactly like yours(similar) .. http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/3070/crj.png .. When I click on the ClearCase menu you marked then "Connect to the rational clearcase" I get that error

Comment: @cOmrade, are you on W7 32 or 64bits, bit a JVM 5 or 6 for Eclipse? With CC7, 7.1.0.X, or 7.1.1? (see for instance http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21273089)

Comment: @VonC It's 64bits, JVM6(tried switching to VJM5 same error) I use CC 7.5.0.v200910221234

Comment: @cOmrade: you do not use CC7.5: that is the version of the plugin, not of ClearCase itself. You might use ClearCase 2003.06 or 7.0.x or 7.1.0.x or 7.1.1 (which is quite different from 7.1.0.x). Only ClearCase 7.1.1 stands a chance of being semi-supported on a W7 64 bits.

Comment: @VonC how do I find out, which CC I use?

Comment: @c0mrade: did you solve the issue? Was it simply because the main ClearCase client wasn't installed in the first place?

Comment: @c0mrade: sorry to hear that. I will make some tests on my own and see if there is any compatibility issue.

Comment: @VonC thanks anyways for your effort, its just problem in win7, in XP everything works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Currently, version 1.6 of the JVM is not supported. To use this integration successfully, you must downgrade to JVM 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the latest version of ClearCase available is 7.1, which is not qualified on Windows 7, maybe the issue is there.

Did you try with in the integration/plugin for other IDE ? (VisualStudio ?)

Can you access your views (snapshot or dynamic) outside of eclipse ?

Comment: @gastush: only the dynamic views are not supported. The rest works.