# how to install clearcase 7.1.1

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I've been googling for a while now, I found some not complete tutorials how to install CC 7.1.1 like this one : [Installing Rational ClearCase Remote Client for Eclipse](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_install_ccrc_eclipse.htm)

Which update site do I add in eclipse to install 7.1.1 ? I need this particular version because it is only one supported in windows 7

Comment: a bit offtopic, but what are the reasons for you to install clear-case?

Comment: @Bozho because its only supported in windows7 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21224586

Comment: no, I meant at all - why not svn/cvs/git/mercurial

Comment: offtopic to me : not directly related to java or eclipse (current tags)

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Caruana it is to eclipse, but java is redundant, yes.

Comment: @Bozho I'm just being asked to work with it, if it was me I'd use svn .. @Jean-Philippe Caruana I'm looking for eclipse plugin, and its a java project.

Comment: asked != made. If I'm asked to work with it again, I'll refuse ;)

Comment: At my company we have to use CC... Avoid it if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ClearCase 7.1.1 is not yet officially supported on Windows7.

CCRC (the remote client) is supported, because it only uses snapshot view (CCWeb view) which works on W7 (only dynamic views are not supported yet)

Finally, the "update" site for CCRC 7.1 should be, [according to this IBM post](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412271):

```
http://yourserver:12080/ccrc/update
```

But that is actually only working for 7.0, not 7.1

(And, as mention in this [upgrade process](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/c_upgr_ccrc_eclipse.htm), you will need to install GEF as well.)

With a CCRC server 7.1.x, You must use a full RCP CCRC 7.1.1 client available on [Passport Advantage](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/).

---

You have two configurations:

- You have installed a full ClearCase client (not the remote client, the complete client), because the VOB server is not "too far" from your workstation.
  Then, in that case, you can add an Eclipse ClearCase plugin. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223).
  It is not a CCRC plugin, but a full ClearCase plugin.
- You have not ClearCase on your workstation. Then the only solution to still access some ClearCase view is a remote client.
  With ClearCase 7.1, you only have a standalone version of the CCRC, not an Eclipse plugin version.
  You had an Eclipse CCRC plugin for ClearCase 7.0. But not for CC7.1

So you need first to qualify your situation. Do you have (independently of Eclipse) a full ClearCase client already installed?

Comment: @VonC what is Passport Advantage?I mean I read in short on this website, do I need to pay to use CC 7.1.1

Comment: @Gandalf: I have fixed the answer. Plus, the full CCRC client is a product, like ClearCase. It is included in the ClearCase price, so no extra-charge. But it is only available through the Passport Advantage site, giving you access to the *full* product downloads (ClearCase, but also CCRC RCP).

Comment: @VonC I found this one http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/ccrc/701/update/plugins/ , I was told I need to install it manually plugins to plugins, features to features

Comment: @Gandalf: true but that is a CCRC plugin 7.0.1. If your CCRC *server* is a 7.1 (or 7.1.1), this plugin might *not* work (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21265409), if your CCRC server is older, it won't work.

Comment: @Gandalf: In short, I am not sure there is an Eclipse plugin for CCRC 7.1. There was, for CCRC 7.0. But not anymore for CCRC 7.1: only a standalone CCRC client based on a RCP (Rich Client Platform) Eclipse.

Comment: @VonC hmm can you provide me with install site for that version?I'll try it in win..

Comment: @Gandalf: that's my point: I have never had an "install site " (or "update site") for an Eclipse CCRC plugin. I always used the CCRC standalone client (a full product you download through the Passport advantage. But only if you are sure of the version of your CCRC server. Can you confirm you have elsewhere a CCRC server 7.1.1? See my completed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse plug-ins exist for CCRC 7.1.2, so that you can install it after the fact on top of any Eclipse based IDE. However, it seems IBM do not have a public update site, you need to point to your Clearcase server, and likely, the admin must have installed the update site there.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working simply by exploding the zip 7.1.1.1-RATL-RCCRC-EXT-FP01.zip. This is an IBM eclipse plugin for RAD, this seems to be working fine for all version of eclipse. Simply copy all the contents in the eclipse directory, you are all set.