# Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase

I am new to clearcase and software development using version control system. I am using clearcase for version management currently. I use eclipse IDE for software development.

I installed clearcase plugin for eclipse over the internet from sourceforge.net website. Some how the plugin does not work.

The softwares that i installed are: IBM Rational Clearcase 7.0, Eclipse Galileo 3.5 and clearcase 2.2.3 plugin for it.

I am not able to checkin or checkout files using the plugin. Can some one give me detailed/step-by-step procedure for using the plugins? What kind of environment to be setup?

Answer (score 3):

You will find how top install the plugin in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223), but I would recommend the official [**IBM** ClearCase for Eclipse plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html) (7.5), not the [sourceforge one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/).

If you see a ClearCase menu, the plugin is installed.

BUT: in order to be able to checkout a file within your project, you need to have it within a ClearCase view (snapshot or dynamic).
That means, the `.project` and `.classpath` needs to be right above your source directory, within your project. (And not in your workspace).

If only your sources are in a ClearCase view, but your `.project` and `.classpath` are 'elsewhere', then all the files within your project won't appear as ''versioned' (blue background) and you won't be able to checkout/checkin them.

[image: Eclipse project with ClearCase]

Comment: Hi Vonc, Thank you very much. I am able to see the clearcase menu in eclipse. i created a dynamic view in clear case and mounted the required vobs on it. Can you tell me how to create the C++ project in eclipse so the .project and .classpath are set correctly.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the "ClearCase SCM Adapter" from IBM (i.e. "the official IBM ClearCase for Eclipse plugin" referred to above) or the IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer.  If you are trying to access one or more Eclipse projects that someone from your team has already put in a VOB, you can use the "File --> Import --> Existing Projects into Workspace" (or better, if your team created a project set file, "File --> Import --> Team Project Set").  If you are creating a new Project, don't "Use default location" but supply a VOB pathname in the Location text box.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to use the IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) version 8.0.x, previously known as the ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC) in version 7.x of ClearCase. CTE is an Eclipse plugin that ships with ClearCase.

In ClearCase version 7.x, CCRC only supports 'web views'. Web views are copy based views that communicate with the ClearCase server via http. They perform well in WAN environments.

In version 8.0, the ClearTeam Explorer (formerly CCRC) adds support for Dynamic views. In 8.0, the ClearTeam Explorer supports both Web and Dynamic views.

If you require Snapshot Views or are using a pre-8.0 version of ClearCase, you should use the ClearCase SCM Adapter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable see your view in the `MyView` of the eclipse. To resolve this issue you have to remove `.ccase_wvreg_lockfile` from currently logged in user profile.