# Can't do ClearCase operations on include files in Eclipse CDT with IBM SCM Adapter plugin

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, eclipse-cdt

When we create a project in Eclipse CDT with the source code in clearcase, SCM adapter plugin won't show any controls to perform clearcase operations on include files(files under "Includes" tag in project layout).

I can do all operations on source files. I observed that any of the include files are **not** attached with Eclipse *propertypages* (do Alt+Enter, it says "No property pages found..."). Could this be the reason?

I wonder why include files doesn't have *propertypages* like source files in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that SCM adapter works is that it will consider the source files under the directory where your `.project` and `.classpath` are located (for details on that principle, see "[Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857)": at least the `.project` must be in a ClearCase view).

If those include files aren't "source files" or are stored outside that project directory, they will be ignored by that ClearCase adapter.
More precisely, if those files ("resources") aren't directly referenced in the `.project`, the ClearCase SCM adapter will ignore them.

The OP comments:

> We have a project structure with linked resources wherein all files are located outside of Eclipse project directory (i.e., outside the directory where `.project` file resides).
>   Yet, the plugin allows us to checkout source files, but not include files.
>
> May be the SCM plugin is scanning the `.project` file alone to identify resources, rather than checking the directory structures.

He confirms that those include files [are, actually, "Discovered"](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) (and not resources directly referenced by the `.project` file)

[image: Discovered Paths in CDT project]

Those kind of resources ("discovered") are likely to be ignored by the ClearCase SCM adapter.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be the case. We have a project structure with linked resources wherein all files are located outside of Eclipse project directory(i.e., outside the directory where .project file resides). Yet, the plugin allows us to checkout source files, but not include files. May be the SCM plugin is scanning the .project file alone to identify resources, rather than checking the directory structures.

Comment: "May be the SCM plugin is scanning the `.project` file alone to identify resources": that is possible, considering if the .project isn't in the view itself, the ClearCase options won't be available at all. I have amended my answer to reflect your observations.

Comment: Any idea why the plugin fails to identify include files only? This happens in Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @ernesto having no direct experience with CDT projects, I wouldn't know for sure. Maybe it is related to the fact that the path isn't directly referenced in the `.project` file, but is "Discovered" (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm)

Comment: That's true! The includes were discovered, not referenced in .project file. Now I need to find out a way to insert them in that file...

Comment: @ernesto interesting. I have included this finding and an illustration in the answer for more visibility.