# How to install TestNG eclipse plugin offline?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

Anyone can help ?

I am having trouble, already unzipped the file I downloaded from the site in the dropins folder, but nothing happens !

I CANNOT use internet to install this, because of some very stupid proxy rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can download the testng plugins, create in your dropins directory a structure [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223)

```
/path/to/mydropins
      testng-eclipse-x.y/
         eclipse/
            features
               org.testng.eclipse_x.y.z.jar
            plugins/
               org.testng.eclipse_x.y.z.jar
```

With '`path/to/mydropins`' a [shared dropins repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854765/how-to-copy-plugins-between-two-eclipses/2854782#2854782) referenced in your [`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) with a:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/<myPath>/mySharedDropins
```

You need to copy both:

- http://beust.com/eclipse/features/org.testng.eclipse_5.14.10.20110228_1533.jar
- http://beust.com/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_5.14.10.20110228_1533.jar

Comment: I've tried this with Juno-SR2 using what is currently available at beust.com; one jar named version 6.8. It doesn't work. Also, the links provided to 5.14 is stale.

Comment: @twqqis yes, I haven't tested with a 4.x, and p2 might enforce a different structure than this old dropins one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below options....
Option 1 : Follow steps in https://www.dev2qa.com/testng-eclipse-plugin/
Option 2 : If using Option 1, TestNG is not reflecting properly in eclipse option 3 from below URL 
https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/
The URL for downloading the Zip file is for version 6.11. If you need a higher version try 
http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/zipped/
I had Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and TestNG 6.14.0 version worked for me.

Comment: From review: please add more explanation to this answer, link only answer may become obsolete if the link gets broken. Try to add the relevant information here and add the link only as a reference.