# testNG installation issue in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I installed testNG in `Eclipse-GANYMEDE`  offline as specified in the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155786/how-to-install-testng-eclipse-plugin-offline)

I used `org.testng.eclipse_5.11.0.28.jar`

But after restart eclipse I couldn't see testNG under following menue path

```
Window --> Show View --> Other --> Java
```

Could anybody figure out what's the issue?

One more finding....
Under selenium installation path inside `libs` I found another `testNG` jar `(testng-6.8.jar)`. If I try to remove that and replace the new jar which mentioned above then it is giving import error in `import org.testng.` in the java class

Answer (score 0):

***********    Please refer below link:

http://seleniumtestingguide.blogspot.in/2013/04/configuring-selenium-webdriver-and.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem in my case is, there is no `install new Software..` option in my eclipse due to some reason. So That's why I need to install the plugin offline