# Install clearcase for eclipse 3.5.2 on linux

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I want to install the plugin clear case for eclipse 3.5.2 on linux and I could not find http url of the plugin package to add it in the "Install New Software"
I download the package as a zip format from IBM but I could not succeed to install it.

Could you please provide me URL for this package

Answer (score 1):

The only information for that plugin are:

- [IBM Rational ClearCase plug-ins](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html)
- [Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.0.0.2](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213)
- **[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.6.0.0](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674)**

The last link is for you, and contain the zip to download.
See "[Problems with clear case plugin eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223)" for installing that zip.

You can also try the **update site**:

```
http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/60/update/windows/
```

---

The [OP Mohamed KALLEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003575/mohamed-kallel) adds:

> I install it, but when run connect to Rational ClearCase, I get a popup with the message:

```
You do not have a license to run ClearCase
```

First, check if there is no obvious license issue, as described in [this technote](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135880), using [`clearlicense`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearlicense.htm) (or if there isn't any [ACL right](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21338365) or [license serer IP address](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21321483) issue).

Check also your exact version of ClearCase. If this is ClearCase LT, it might not be supported through an Eclipse plugin. If this is CCRC (ClearCase Remote Control), then this isn't the right plugin.

Comment: I install it, but when run connect to rational clearcase I get a popup with the message: You do not have a license to run ClearCase

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL I have edited my answer to address your comment. What OS are you using? (Windows, Unix?) What ClearCase version are you using?

Comment: I run my ClearCase on Linux and in the Installed Software I see 2 packages installed "Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter" (7.0.0.20070612B) and Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (7.0.0.20081031A)

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: what does return a `cleartool -verall` ? and `clearlicense` ?

Comment: @moh: It is a clearcase command.  If ClearCase is installed, you should find it.

Comment: @moh: try a find / -name cleartool, in order to find the complete path of that command

Comment: both command are not found and the package is installed in the eclipse

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL then I confirm that the "package" alone (ie the ClearCase plugin for Eclipse) won't be enough to allow you any ClearCase operation. You need a full ClearCase installation in addition of that plugin.

Comment: have you a link for the full installation of the clearCase on linux?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL sure, beside my own process (http://serverfault.com/questions/49786/how-do-you-install-clearcase-7-1-on-a-unix-based-server-with-no-gui-and-no-inter), the updated version of that same process is at http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21579102&myns=swgrat&mynp=OCSSSH27&mync=R