# Why is there no association with ClearCase for my Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, clearcase, checkin, vcs-checkout

I am using rational ClearCase and eclipse Helios 3.3.2.
I was created view in ClearCase Explorer, then imported the code into my workspace.

After this, to link the eclipse project with ClearCasen I am clicking on the project then Team.
But, it is not showing "`associate with clearCase`" option.
It is showing "`apply patch`" and some other.

What is the reason behind this?
How can I link the workspace with ClearCase?

Comment: what plugin do you use for clearcase? I think there are 2 available - open source one from the sourcefoge (however with this one I remember quite some load on PC resources), another one is from IBM (available on http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24024213) this one I have used, and once clicking ClearCase -> Connect to Rational Clearcase this worked without any further actions for me

Comment: I didn't add any plugins externally to eclipse,already clear case plugins are installed in my machine.

Comment: Eclipse alone doesn't know about ClearCase. You need to install the plugin as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223 But first, what version of ClearCase are you using. What is your platform (OS, 32 or 64 bits)?

Comment: @Vonc..I don't know exactlly version of clearcase.I am using windows xp.In my team nobody added clearcase plugins,we got the eclipse with plugins installed.For other peoples its working fine,but in my system it's not working.Is my question sufficient to give answer or any datails will need?

Comment: @Vonc.When I am clicking on window->preferences->team then there is no clearcase option.It means clearcase plugin  not installed in my eclipse?

Comment: Please delete your new question. All the details are in my answer to *this* question below. As for the version of ClearCase, type `cleartool -ver` or look for the about option in the help menu of the ClearCase Explorer.

Comment: Second, check if the pugin is present in your Eclipse, as described in the picture of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Peter B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1581069/peter-b), the official ClearCase should be used here: "
[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.6.0.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674)" (ie not the 7.0.0.2, rather the 7.6+)

If not installed properly, the safest way is to re-install a fresh copy of Eclipse (here 3.3+) and the plugin itself, checking if the issue persists.

See "[Problems with clear case plugin eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223)" on the installation process.

However, another common cause for *not* seing the association with this plugin is if the `.project` and `.classpath` files aren't directly with the sources within the ClearCase view, but are kept *outside* the view.
See "[Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857)" for an illustration of that issue.

Comment: Hi VonC, where we can find .project and .class files in the clear case.Can you provide any screen shot for detail understand.

Comment: @user1552438 if your dynamic view contains your sources, that's where those two eclipse files should be. In the screenshot of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857, you see `src`, `.settings`, `bin`, etc. The `.eclipse` and `.classpath` should be right in that same directory.

Comment: @user1552438 Excellent, what was the issue?