# Rational clearcase client integration with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I am using Eclipse 3.2.0 and Rational clear case client 7.1.2 on my local machine.
I want to install plugin for same (Rational clear case client 7.1.2) on eclipse.
Can someone please give me **download link for Rational clear case client 7.1.2 plugin** and also gide me in integrating it with eclipse?

Thanks,
Tushar.

Answer (score 2):

For a CCRC installation (ClearCase Remote Client, which comes with its own Eclipse-based RCP - Rich client Platform - for ClearCase):

See "[Installing or updating CCRC for Eclipse and RSA](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21215611)" (and its [process here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_install_ccrc_eclipse.htm))

[image: CCRC update site]

(See also the compatibility matrix between Eclipse and CCRC)

**The CCRC plugin is stored within your CCRC server at: `http://<computer-name>/ccrc/update`**, where `<computer-name>` is the name of the computer that has Rational® ClearCase® and the CM Server for Rational ClearCase Remote Client installed on it.

---

For a full ClearCase client installation:

You will find the SCM adapter at IBM in "
[Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter (For Eclipse), Version 7.6.0.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674)".

> For Eclipse versions 3.2.2 to 3.3.x inclusive:
>
> - Download the zip file appropriate for your operating system. Extract the contents of the file to a directory in your file system.
> - In Eclipse, select `Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration`. In the `Product Configuration` window, click the "`Add an Extension Location`" link in the Eclipse platform pane.
> - The Browse for Folder dialog prompts you to choose an extension location, expand the My Computer entry and navigate to the directory that contains the contents of the extracted zip file. Expand the Eclipse folder and click "OK".
> - The Install/Update dialog prompts you to restart the workbench. Click "Yes".
> - In the Eclipse window, click Window > Customize Perspective.
> - In the Customize Perspective dialog box, click the Commands tab, ensure that the ClearCase option under the Available command groups column is checked, and click "OK".

See more at:

- "[Clearcase plugin for eclipse usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393758/clearcase-plugin-for-eclipse-usage/3393857#3393857)"
- "[Problems with ClearCase plugin eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462979/problems-with-clear-case-plugin-eclipse/2463223#2463223)"
- "[What ClearCase plugin to use with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#1175738)"

Comment: I allready installed plugin for V 7.6.0 but it is giving me eror:: Could not connect to Rational Clearcase. Please ensure that the proper version of ClearCase is installed with the proper patches. Consult the ClearCase SCM Adapter documentation for futher details. Provider name: IBM Plugin name: Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter Plugin ID: com.rational.clearcase Version: 7.6.0.v201105111445

Comment: @user1852552 What is your OS? and Os version? What is your ClearCase version? Are you using ClearCase or CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client)?

Comment: OS: Windows XP sp2  ClearCase :: Rational Clear case remote client Version: 7.1.2

Comment: @user that is your issue : the SCM adapter is for a full ClearCase installation, not for RTC.

Comment: but can I get plugin for version 7.1.2? becouse currently client installed is of V 7.1.2 and plugin that I am having is of V 7.6.0 so it's mismatch. I want to try with plugin V 7.1.2 on eclipse.

Comment: @user1852552 The V7.6.0 is for an Eclipse to use a full ClearCase, not for a CCRC.