# Clear case - Eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase

1. currently I am having following [image]version of clear case on my local machine.
2. I downloded plugin "com.rational.clearcase.win32-20081031A" from url: "http://www3.software.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/clearcase/ccplugin/com.rational.clearcase.win32-20081031A.zip" which include following [image]files in feature and plugin folders.
   3.then I installed this plugin from eclipse Help->Software update-> search and install->given here local path of plugin folder which looks like following screen shot[image] 4. It got installed on eclipse;but when I am trying tu connect through it it's giveing me following[image] error.

can you please suggest whats going wrong in it?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin won't work with CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client), only with a full base ClearCase installation.

CCRC comes with its own Eclipse interface, in which you will find all the necessary ClearCase commands.

If you want a CCRC plugin (which is different from the [SCM Adaptor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674) you have downloaded), you need to download it from your CCRC server, [as I detail in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560168/6309).