# Error in clearcase connection through plugin from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase

I have successfully installed Rational clear case client 7.1.2 plugin on Eclipse but I am getting following error while connecting to it :

ERROR :-

```
The server cannot be contacted.  Please contact your system administrator.; 
nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
```

Can some one please suggest how to troubleshoot this error message?

Answer (score 1):

[Bug 295161](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=295161) suggests a class loading issue.

But if the plugin is correctly installed, I have seen this error when trying to use said plugin with a CCRC access (ClearCase Remote Control), instead of a full *local* ClearCase installation.

[Technote swg21373322](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373322) details the other causes:

[image: error]

- One possible cause is that `C:\Program Files\IBM\RationalSDLC\common` is too far down in the system Path environment variable.
  => to check
- A memory allocation issue on the WAS server.
  => to see with your admin
- This error also occurs if the user does not use the full and correct Team URL. For example, if the user enters `http://myserver` or `http://myserver:12080`.
  => to check
- This error may also occur as a result of defect APAR PK91671.
- There are no ClearCase licenses. ClearCase licenses may not be setup properly on the license server host.
- This may occur if the server has region map enabled and the user region map file has restrictive permission's or was incorrectly placed in a directory that has restrictive permission's.
- This can also occur if the CCRC temp directory is not writable by the remote-user attempting login.
- The installed client version may not be compatible with the CM server version.
  (I don't think this is the case here)

---

This [other IBM help page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/qualitymanagement/entry/one_stop_for_ccrc_integration_with_rft29?lang=en) mentions [technote swg21500584](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21500584):

You might need to check your proxy:

[image: Eclipse proxy]

> Eclipse users will notice that in recent versions of Eclipse (3.4 and later) there is a active provider set to Native by default. The above is the default installation of Eclipse on a network that does not have proxies.
>
> Native and Direct are the choices for Active Providers.
>   Below is the description on Eclipse 3.6 (for example releases like 3.5 are the same) for that preference value:
>
> "Specifies the settings profile to be used when opening connections.
>
> - Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server.
> - Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used.
>
> On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used."

Comment: ... and that seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600172/clear-case-eclipse-integration and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559943/rational-clearcase-client-integration-with-eclipse

Comment: can you please suggest how to handle this issue? is it specific to any version of eclipse?

Comment: @user1852552 yes, can you tell me the version of your ClearCase (cleartool -ver), Eclipse version, jdk version used for launching Eclipse, and the ClearCase plugin for Eclipse exact version (or the url form which you got that plugin)?

Comment: following is detail:   Clear case remote client (standalone) :Rational ClearCase Remote Client
Version: 7.1.2
Build id: 7.1.2.01.00_2010D.D101206 - Able to connect through this   ||   Plug-in : Rational clear case remote client for 7.1.2.v20101207013  || installed from server location where clear case is installed by url: http://<computer-name>/ccrc/update  || Eclipse : 3.5.0 || JDK 6

Comment: @user1852552 Ok. I have edited the answer with a link to an IBM technote which will help you solve the issue.

Comment: Again I installed Eclipse 3.4.2 and installed CCRC plugin same as above here I am getting bellow error wile connecting to cleacase: Cannot connect to host https://clt-ccweb.ba******.com/TeamWeb/services/Team. If this problem cannot be resolved, you can work disconnected. ; nested exception is: java.net.UnknownHostException: clt-ccweb.ba******.com

Comment: @user1852552 ok: did you check the technote I mention in my answer? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373322 Was there any resolution in that technote that was helpful?

Comment: @user1852552 Regarding your new error message, check out http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21509439 or http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21500584 (after https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/qualitymanagement/entry/one_stop_for_ccrc_integration_with_rft29?lang=en): I have edited my answer. I suspect a proxy issue.